# SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 in my Rails 3 development environment instead of MySQL but I'm running into a problem. When trying to do `rake db:migrate` I get:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"`

Obviously there isn't a users table yet as I'm trying to set up the database. Do I need to run something before I try to migrate?

***Rakefile***

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'
Skateparks::Application.load_tasks
```

***Source Code***

Please feel free to poke through all of my source code for this project on [Github](http://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web).

***Trace***

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:207:in `rescue in log'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:199:in `log'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:135:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:284:in `select'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:56:in `select_all'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:473:in `find_by_sql'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `to_a'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation.rb:13:in `collect'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/app/models/skatepark/comment.rb:33:in `<class:Comment>'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/app/models/skatepark/comment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/spec/factories.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/factory_girl-2.0.3/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:16:in `block in find_definitions'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/factory_girl-2.0.3/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/factory_girl-2.0.3/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.1.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:11:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:46:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:218:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Comment: Is there more to this error? If so please show it here. A stacktrace can be helpful for tracking down where this is coming from.

Comment: I updated my post w/ what I get w/ `rake db:migrate --trace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line: https://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web/blob/master/app/models/skatepark/comment.rb#L33

You are making a call to the `User` model which attempts to load the `users` table. Rather than doing this, why not have a foreign key constraint?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think of that as being the cause of the problem. I'll be sure to update that and everything similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have ran     rake db:create    ?

Comment: Yes. I've already ran that. If I try to run it again I get: ```db/test.sqlite3 already exists
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
db/development.sqlite3 already exists
db/development.sqlite3 already exists``` I seems as if it's running this twice. Strange.